# Getting rid of Plesk on a VPS

Tags: linux, centos, hosting, vps

I've been using a relatively expensive VPS for hosting about 30 domains and I want to migrate to a cheaper one, without Plesk. Both use CentOS.

My users will not care, they don't use Plesk anyway.

But I will not be able to use it for creating new virtual hosts, FTP accounts etc. I'm not a commandline guru, esp. not in a server environment.

Is there a free Plesk alternative for these purposes? I need to:

- Create a new virtual host with it's own FTP account
- Setup some basic FTP quota

I don't need:

- DNS management (the new VPS service has an external DNS management GUI)
- Mail server management (I use Google Apps)

Any suggestions welcome, from Plesk alternatives to "RTFM" or links to tutorials.

Comment: This looks promising: http://www.ispconfig.org/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Cost is a bad reason to move off of Plesk.  They are clearly providing value to you, the freedom from having to understand what's actually going on under the hood.

The right reason to move off Plesk is because you don't like what it does under the hood, and want to take back control.  You can save a few bucks a month that way, which you almost immediately eat up by spending time doing things by hand that Plesk used to do for you automatically.

I say this as someone who moved his site off a VPS running Plesk to a bare-bones VPS service.  But then, I *am* a command line guru. :)

Answer (score 1):

My two cents is keep plesk. It makes managment a dead simple task and makes it very easy to see what is going on with your server. I am a command line semiguru however I like plesk because it is web based access from anywhere no ssh client needed, and gives a quick visualization of what is going on with the server usage.